# Why PHP doesn't show my custom error message when mysqli_connect fails?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to connect to the database, and when I try with everything correct, the database connects, and everything is fine. But, when I try to connect using some wrong credentials, it throws an error message, and I am figuring out a way to hide the error message from the user.

```
function connectDatabase(){
        $dbServerName = 'local_host';
        $dbUsername = 'root';
        $dbPassword = '';
        $dbName = 'kishor_me';

        $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServerName, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
        
        if (!$conn) {
            echo "error message";
        }else{
            echo "success message";
        }
    }
```

Isn't there any way I can show the user the critical error message and not the other error description generated by the language and also not give an HTTP 500 error? Please let me know if there is any way or if this question has already been answered.

Comment: You **shouldn't**. Such a petty part of your application should **never** talk to a user on its own

Comment: Yeah, So I believe a custom error message from my side is required. But, I am not being able to hide the error message. I don't know if there is any way or not but I was not able to find any solutions to this.

Comment: You could switch off the displaying of errors: `ini_set('display_errors', '0');`. This will still log the errors normally, but just don't echo them to the user. See: [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors).

Comment: You are. Setting display_errors to OFF hides ALL error messages at once. **This** is what is expected from you, instead of tinkering with some arbitrary parts of your code.

Comment: @kikosoftware, is there anything I should be concerned about? Or any effects of using the ```ini_set('display_errors', '0');```??

Comment: In case you want a custom message, you can configure an error/exception handler like this https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting#error_page

Comment: @KishorNeupane the main effect of that is you won't see any error messages, and therefore it will be very difficult to debug your code if it doesn't work as expected. If you're going to do that, you should also configure it to log the error messages to a file instead, so you can check them there. That's what you should always be doing on any live server anyway, so you don't accidentally leak sensitive information to users (who might not be honest users). You should _never_ attempt to deliberately `echo` error information into your application's output. See the guide in the link just above.

Comment: No, you shouldn't be concerned. However, as Adyson said: You yourself also won't see error messages in the browser. If you have a fixed IP address, that you use alone, you could check that, and set `display_errors` to ON when `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` contains your IP, and OFF when it doesn't. That way you can still see the messages.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you are using some outdated tutorial, that offers incorrect approach at reporting errors: a code that tries to detect the connection error manually and outputs something on its own. But your code shouldn't be doing anything like that: both PDO and mysqli can raise errors *automatically* and, moreover, such a part of your code *should never talk to the user on its own*.

Let's answer your question step by step:

#### How to detect a connection error

In the ancient times, some 10 years ago, PHP used [mysql extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php) to talk to MySQL database, which was unable to handle errors automatically, and every database operation had to be checked for errors manually. That's where this `if (!$conn) {` stuff is coming from. But this ext is long gone, and PHP got a new one, mysqli. Which has the ability to raise errors automatically, just like any other command in PHP, `include` or `header()` for example. You aren't checking every `include` or `header()` result manually, are you? *So you shouldn't with mysqli or PDO.*

As you can see, `mysqli_connect()` (as well as `new mysqli()` or `new PDO()`) produces the error automatically, just like any other PHP function. So there is just no use for the `if (!$conn) {` part. Neither on connect, nor with `query()` or any other database function.

In a nutshell: you don't need any code to detect database errors. They are regular errors now. And, if you think of it, not only database errors must be hidden. Any other error, like "Headers already sent" or "No such file or directory" must be hidden from a site user as well.

So the problem is more generic now:

#### How to hide all error messages from a site user

To hide error messages from a site user, you must use a configuration option which is intended exactly for that: `display errors`. While set to `0`, it will prevent PHP from displaying *any* error occurred. It's best to be set in the `php.ini` but in case you don't have a control over PHP configuration, at least you can set it right in the PHP code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

The best part of it, this is just a single place where it's set. Therefore, on your local PC or on a test server you can set it to 1 and watch all errors online. *Again, without any changes in the code:* as you can see, a failed connection attempt already provided a detailed error message, without that `if (!$conn) {` stuff. But on a live server, `display errors` must be set to 0, so not a single error message leaks to the user, while `log_errors` must be set to 1. That's a simple rule which is, sadly, seldom mentioned in the books or tutorials. By the way, I'd recommend PHP&MySQL book by Jon Duckett, where this approach is explained in detail.

#### Connection credentials

Even when credentials are not displayed, some people feel uneasy when sensitive information even gets logged. Update your PHP version. Starting from 8.2, it hides the database password from the stack trace.

#### How to handle connection error

If you want to test the credentials, for example when running the installation script, you can wrap the connection in a try..catch. But you shouldn't do that in a production code. Or in case you have a backup scenario when a connection fails, you can also wrap the connection in a try..catch. In a nutshell, use try..catch if you have a handling scenario other than just report the error, in which case just leave the connection code alone.

So the only question remains is "How to show the user the critical error message?".

#### How to display a nice error page to a site user

Simply configure an *error handler*. Here is one from my article on [PHP error reporting](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting):

```
set_exception_handler(function ($e)
{
    error_log($e);
    http_response_code(500);
    if (ini_get('display_errors')) {
        echo $e;
    } else {
        echo "<h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1>
              An internal server error has been occurred.<br>
              Please try again later.";
    }
});
```

depends on the `display_errors` value, it will either display the error itself, or just a generic message.

---

Note that it "gives an HTTP 500 error" which, contrary to your request, is what actually *must* be done. When your page cannot provide the actual content due to server error, it must respond with 5xx HTTP code.