# How is it possible to use if on mysqli result object?

Tags: php, boolean

It may be obvious question, but I don't understand how does it work.

For the following code in PHP:

```
$connection = new mysqli("host","user","password","database");
$result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM `table`;");
if($result)
{
// do something
}
```

I don't understand how it is possible to make an operation if ($result) on object since it's not a simple bool variable, but collection of variables and methods.

How is it possible?

How does this mechanism work?

Can I make my own objects that also allow to make "invisible" bool variable in it?

Comment: It *is* a simple bool value *in certain circumstances*: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php#refsect1-mysqli.query-returnvalues

Comment: That value can either be the boolean value `false` or an object. The `if` statement in php can well work with such mixed values. Which is necessary, since php is a type weak language. So a language where any variable can assume values of arbitrary types.

Comment: PHP is a loosely typed language. ANY variable will be implicitly cast to boolean when in appropriate context.

Comment: Note that you should never use if($result) with mysqli, it's useless *and* a bad practice.

Comment: @YourCommonSense so, what should I use instead?

Comment: Nothing. It used to be the way to check for errors but now it's obsoleted. Mysqli will report errors without this code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884566/285587

Comment: Okay, but how to handle this error and give information to user such as "Internal error"? Use try-catch or something?