# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function stmt_init() on int in X Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in X

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error after trying to run /process-signup.php, im trying to code a signup-login system but im blocked here.

CODE FOR "process-signup.php";

```
<?php

if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
    die("Username is required");
}

if (strlen($_POST["password"]) < 8) {
    die("Password must be at least 8 characters");
}

if ( ! preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $_POST["password"])) {
    die("Password must contain at least one letter");
}

if ( ! preg_match("/[0-9]/", $_POST["password"])) {
    die("Password must contain at least one number");
}

if ($_POST["password"] !== $_POST["repassword"]) {
    die("Passwords must match");
}

$password_hash = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/config.php";

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, password)
        VALUES (?, ?)";

$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();

if ( ! $stmt->prepare($sql)) {
    die("SQL error: " . $mysqli->error);
}

$stmt->bind_param("sss",
                $_POST["username"],
                $password_hash);

$stmt->execute();


echo "Signup successfull";
?>
```

**CODE OF "config.php";**

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'login_db','3306');

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

I really dont know where the problem is, i expect a "Sign Up successfully"

Comment: Your connection object isn't called `$mysqli`, it's called `$conn`. You yourself wrote the code which named it `$conn`.

Comment: `$mysqli = require`....makes no sense as an assignment because the config.php file doesn't `return` anything. Therefore `require` will simply return `1` instead - as per the php documentation. Hence the reference to `int` in the error message. When you `require` a file, the variables and functions etc declared within it automatically become available within the script which calls the `require` function, without you needing to return anything from that file, or assign anything from the call to `require`. Have another, closer look at the documentation and examples of usage online.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the return value of `require` to `$mysqli`. By default this returns `1` when it's successful, so you're setting `$mysqli` to `1`, not the database connection object.

You have two options:

1. Use `$conn` rather than `$mysqli` in the main script.
2. Change `config.php` to return the connection.

```
<?php

return new mysqli('localhost','root', '', 'login_db','3306');
```

When an include file executes `return`, that value becomes the value of the `include` or `require` call.

Comment: @YourCommonSense why did you remove the error checking?

Comment: Because it's wrong *and* obsoleted anyway. [Does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/285587). [Why PHP doesn't show my custom error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884566/285587)

Comment: Unless you wrap in `try/catch` it's going to die anyway.

Comment: Exactly. Going to die anyway, *controllably and configurably*, following error reporting settings configured for the entire site. It's much better than such blunt manual "checking". That's the point.