# Try catch not catching error . mysqli / PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, try-catch

I am testing my error handling for mysqli by attempting to close an already a closed statement.  Even though the second $stmt->close() is throwing an error, the catch is not being executed. I've researched other similar questions, but their solution, adding the mysqli_report call, doesn't help.  I have the exact same construct in place for trapping other mysqli errors and it works in many instances. However in others I have this same issue - catch is just not invoked.

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

// ... bunch of other code here, including successful connect and write to DB .... then...

// Close statement and connection
$stmt->close();
try {$stmt->close();}
catch (Exception $e) {
    respond_forInsert (false, 400, "CAUGHT!");
     exit
}
```

Error Message:

**Fatalerror**: UncaughtError: mysqli_stmtobjectisalreadyclosedinC: \Users\16305\LocalSites\easy-street-2\app\public\ee\api\lead\chat_session\insert_record.php: 178Stacktrace: #0C: \Users\16305\LocalSites\easy-street-2\app\public\ee\api\lead\chat_session\insert_record.php(178): mysqli_stmt->close()#1{
main
}thrownin**C: \Users\16305\LocalSites\easy-street-2\app\public\ee\api\lead\chat_session\insert_record.php**online**178**

Comment: Are you sure it's throwing an error, not just printing a warning?

Comment: Are you inside a namespace? Try a leading backslash like `catch (\Exception $e)` to anchor.

Comment: Use `Error` instead of `Exception`.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do? Why are you catching errors like this? What's special about mysqli errors?

Comment: `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT | MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` this combination doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Just for the record. You shouldn't be doing anything like that.

Comment: @Dharman It's not obvious why changing to `Error` fixes it. The documentation of `mysqli_sql_exception` says it's a subclass of `RuntimeException`, which is a subclass of `Exception`.

Comment: @Barmar The user is not trying to catch `mysqli_sql_exception`. As you can see in the error message they shared, they just trigger a normal PHP `Error`. Errors and Exceptions are not the same.

Comment: But this is why I ask what's so special about errors triggered by mysqli functions? An error is an error irregardless of which function is to blame. Just fix the code and you don't need to have any try-catch.

Comment: To put it in other words: if you forgot to put a semicolon after `$stmt->close()` is a parse error, but it's not specific to mysqli extension. It's just a programmer error that requires fixing the source code. Don't special-case these errors. Even `mysqli_sql_exception` should not be treated with special care unless you are writing code that by design should recover from an exceptional situation.

Comment: @Dharman That's raises another question. The documentation of `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` says it turns warnings into `mysqli_sql_exception`.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, what is the question?

Comment: @Dharman `mysqli_sql_execption` is a supposedly subclass of `Exception`, not `Error`, so `catch (Exception $e)` should catch it. But it needs to be `catch (Error $e)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257102/discussion-between-dharman-and-barmar).

Comment: Barmar nailed it.  He says in comments...

" @Dharman mysqli_sql_execption is a supposedly subclass of Exception,
not Error, so catch (Exception $e) should catch it. But it needs to be
 catch (Error $e)"

Catching Error instead of exception did it!
I had tried mysqli_sql_execption but not Error.  Pretty new to PHP, so didn't even know there was a distinction between Error and Exception. Will read up on it.
Thanks!

Comment: @LarryHolze Yes, if you want to catch both use `Throwable` but I would still question why you need to do that at all. Please rething your reason for try-catch.

Comment: [You aren't wrapping every include or header() in a try-catch, are you? So you shouldn't with mysqli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74884566/285587)